# Disabling of EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, I have an EditText that the user only has Read access not Write access.

In code I set `android:enabled="false"`.

Although the background of EditText changed to dark, when I click on it the keyboard pops up and I can change the text.

What should I set to disable EditText?

Comment: It's possible to preserve both the style of the view and the scrolling behaviour. To disable an `EditText` while keeping this properties, just use `UI.setReadOnly(myEditText, true)` from [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib). If you want to replicate this behaviour without the library, check out [the source code](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/62299c79d100e38627600907e755d563de072234/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/UI.java#L264) for this small method.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

I believe the correct would be to set [`android:editable="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:editable).

And if you wonder why my link point to the attributes of `TextView`, you the answer is because [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) inherits from `TextView`:

> EditText is a thin veneer over
>   TextView that configures itself to be
>   editable.

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comments below, `editable` is deprecated ([since API level 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#editable)). You should instead be using [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType) (with the value `none`).

Comment: thanks Nailuj, unfortunately it didn't work. After adding your suggestion keyboard pops up and there is ability to change the text.

Comment: @Hesam: I suspect you're doing something wrong then. If you read the documentation for the `android:editable` attribute, it says that the `TextView` (and `EditText` which inherits from the `TextView`) will not have an input method if this attribute is set to `false`. I also just tested this myself, and setting `android:editable="false"` on an `EditText` in my own application makes it impossible to write text in it (it is still possible to position the cursor inside it though). You should post an example from your code, then we might see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: thanks Nailuj, Yes you told correct. I put your code in a wrong place. however, after I correct it, it works fine.

Comment: android:editable is deprecated. android:inputType="none" should be used instead but it contains bug and it does not work. It would be nice if we all star the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2854

Comment: `editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

Comment: @ViktorBrešan also when I have multiline EditText and I set android:inputType="none" it changes it to single line. It's a heck to disable a multiline EditText yet let the user read the entire text.

Comment: `android:editable="false" android:focusable="false"` works great for me (forget about deprecated, i think android:editable has nothing to do with android:inputType)

Comment: The issue for me is that the wrapping breaks when I do this. EditText doesn't seem to wrap correctly.

Comment: For all those, for whom android:inputType="none" isn't working, try:
android:inputType="none" with android:focusable="false"

Answer (score 189):

use `EditText.setFocusable(false)`  to disable editing
`EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` to enable editing;

Comment: It works, but it's not a good practice because the view looks like it can be editable but it can't. Worked fine for me because my View had a custom background, so +1.

Comment: @kaneda. I actually prefer this. I don't want my box greyed out. :)

Comment: In Android 4.4, this options keeps the original text colour. Using `editText.setEnabled(false);` will change the text colour to grey. However, spinners does not change the text colour when using `setEnabled`, making it an inconsistent experience.

Comment: why not `setFocusable(true)` ? see this link for the difference between `setFocusable()` and `setFocusableInTouchMode()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799064/what-is-the-difference-between-setfocusable-and-setfocusableintouchmode

Comment: This really fit my needs. I created a compound custom view with an EditText inside. I am having problem making the custom view of mine to just accept clicks but not editable as this launches a date picker dialog. This solution works as it doesn't disable onClickListeners

Comment: but you still can make long tab on EditText view and paste text from clipboard

Comment: to prevent long touch you can also add 'android:longClickable="false"' as specified in a comment on an answer below.

Answer (score 78):

You can try the following method :

```
 private void disableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setFocusable(false);
    editText.setEnabled(false);
    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
    editText.setKeyListener(null);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
 }
```

Enabled EditText :

[image: Enabled EditText]

Disabled EditText :

[image: Disabled EditText]

It works for me and hope it helps you.

Comment: This looks like a TextView. It's so amazing. This is what I looking for.

Comment: In case someone has the same problem with enabling back - you got to call `editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` instead of `editText.setFocusable(true)`.

Answer (score 72):

Use this to disable user input

```
android:focusable="false"
```

**android:editable="false"** This method is deprecated one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting input type to 'none' as suggested in other answers does not (always) work. Setting enabled to 'false' prevents editing but also dims the text which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 55):

For disable edit `EditText`, I think we can use `focusable` **OR** `enable` but

1. Using `android:enabled=...` or `editText.setEnabled(...)`

   It also **changes** the text color in `EditText` to gray.
   When clicked it have no effect
2. Using `android:focusable=...` or `editText.setFocusable(false)` - `editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`

   It **doesn't change** text color of `EditText`
   When clicked it highlights the `EditText` bottom line for about few millisecond

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You can add `android:longClickable="false"` along with `android:focusable="false"` to remove the temporary highlight when touching this view.  This also prevents the "select all" popup from appearing.

Comment: @CzarMatt instead  you should use cursor visible to false

Comment: using enter of keyboard and imeoptions next from previous edittext you can still type there

Comment: How make the text selectable when android:focusable="false"?

Answer (score 21):

As `android:editable="false"` is depricated.You can use InputType [TYPE_NULL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NULL) on EditText

**use like this :**

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: Liked this answer because it does not disable the onClickListener on the field.

Comment: what to do if the inputType is password? TYPE_NULL makes password visible.

Comment: Thanks! It works together with `android:focusable="false"`, while `android:inputType="none"` doesn't. In that case we can paste text via long click.

Answer (score 21):

As `android:editable="false"` deprecated 
In `xml`

> Use `android:enabled="false"` it's simple. Why use more code?

If you want in `java class` you can also use this programmatically

```
 editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: use android:enabled="true" for enable

Comment: this disable the scroll and in my case I want to disable the editing but not the scroll

Answer (score 9):

Simply:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: How does it differ from the previous answer (so as question)?

Comment: setFocusable(false) also lets you set an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 9):

I use google newly released Material Design Library. In my case, it works when I use
android:focusable="false" and
android:cursorVisible="false"

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/to_time_input_layout"
                    app:endIconMode="custom"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_clock"
                    app:endIconContentDescription="ToTime"
                    app:endIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    style="@style/OutlinedEditTextStyle"
                    android:hint="To Time">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/to_time_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:cursorVisible="false" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

To disable the functionality of an EditText, just use:

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

in case you want to enable it some way, then you can use:

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: what to do if the inputType is password? TYPE_NULL makes password visible.

Comment: yeah this breaks any kind of specific input (like in my case textMultiLine)

Answer (score 6):

## Disable = FOCUS+CLICK+CURSOR

Disabling focus, click, and cursor visibility does the trick for me.

> Here is the code in XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    />
```

Answer (score 5):

Set below properties in class:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

It will work smoothly as you required.

Comment: only `enabled` was sufficient

Answer (score 5):

This will make your edittext **disabled**.

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

And by using this

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Will just make your Edittext **not show** your softkeyboard, but if it is connected to a physical keyboard, it will let you type.

Comment: what to do if the inputType is password? TYPE_NULL makes password visible.

Answer (score 4):

if you use `android:editable="false"`, eclipse will remind you this message "android:editable is deprecated: Use inputType instead".

So, I use `android:focusable="false"` instead, it worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
android:editable="false"
```

is now deprecated and use

```
 YourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: what to do if the inputType is password? TYPE_NULL makes password visible.

Comment: @ilyamuromets This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16720520/7704650 with `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` Follow this for more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType

Comment: I want to disable input in the EditText while soft keyboard is opened and user trying to input text. InputType.TYPE_NULL works great with isFocusable and isFocusableInTouchMode in false value. But if inputType of the input field is textPassword then InputType.TYPE_NULL make password value visible. If I set InputType.TYPE_NULL | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD then password also becomes visible and user might input text.

Answer (score 4):

Using `android:editable="false"` is Depracted. Instead you'll need to Use `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: using enter of keyboard and imeoptions next from previous edittext you can still type there

Answer (score 3):

Use `TextView` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one, works fine for me:**

```
public class CustomEdittext extends EditText {

Boolean mIsTextEditor=true;
public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mIsTextEditor;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mIsTextEditor=false;
    Boolean mOnTouchEvent=super.onTouchEvent(event);
    mIsTextEditor=true;     
    return mOnTouchEvent;
} }
```

Note: You need to add `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`
on your activity or else `keyboard` will **popup** at first time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed my `EditText` to scroll text if no. of lines exceed `maxLines` when its disabled. This implementation worked perfectly for me.

```
private void setIsChatEditTextEditable(boolean value)
{
    if(value)
    {
        mEdittext.setCursorVisible(true);
        mEdittext.setSelection(chat_edittext.length());
       // use new EditText(getApplicationContext()).getKeyListener()) if required below
        mEdittext.setKeyListener(new AppCompatEditText(getApplicationContext()).getKeyListener());  
    }
    else
    {
        mEdittext.setCursorVisible(false);
        mEdittext.setKeyListener(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As some answer mention it, if you disable the editText he become gray and if you set focusable false the cursor is displaying.

If you would like to do it only with xml this did the trick

```
       <YourFloatLabel
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/view_ads_search_select"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"/>  
       </YourFloatLabel>
```

I simply add a FrameLayout appear above the editText and set it focusable and clickable so the editText can't be click.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

android:focusable="false"

Comment: How is this different than what Sampath Kumar posted 4 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

From @Asymptote's comment on the accepted answer, use:

```
myEditText.setEnabled(false);
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

...and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Today I still use `editable="false"`, but also with `focusable="false"`.

I think the case we need to make an EditText un-editable, is because we want to keep its EditText style (with that underline, with hint, etc), but it accepts other inputs instead of text. For example a dropdown list.

In such use case, we need to have the `EditText` clickable (thus `enabled="false"` is not suitable). Setting `focusable="false"` do this trick, however, **I can still long hold on the EditText and paste my own text onto it from clipboard**. Depending on your code and handling this can even crash your app.

So I also used `editable="false"` and now everything is great, except the warning.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:focusable="false"` but also need to disable cursor otherwise 
copy/paste function would still work.

so, use

```
android:focusable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple was how to achieve multiple levels of disabled.

- `editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);` and `editText.setFocusable`

prevents the `EditText` from showing keyboard - writing in some text. But cursor is still visible and user can paste in some text.

- `editText.setCursorVisible(false)`

hides the cursor. Not sure why would you want to do that tho. User can input text & paste.

- `editText.setKeyListener(null)`

I find this way most convenient. There is no way how user can input text, but widget still works with `OnClickListener` if you want to trigger action when user touches it

- `editText.setEnabled(false);`

completely disables `EditText`. It is literally 'read-only', user cannot input any text in it and (for example) `OnClickListener` **doesn't** work with it.

TextEdit [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ext function in **Kotlin**:

```
fun EditText.disableInput() {
    isFocusable = false
    isEnabled = false
    isCursorVisible = false
    keyListener = null
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
```

like so:

```
myEditText.disableInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above don't really work in all cases, e.g. the Talkback mode.

I added an additional view on top of the `EditText` and assigned a click listener to it.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/btnTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Helper functions:

```kotlin
    private fun makeOverlayEditTextEditable(
        editText: EditText,
        clickOverlayView: View,
        inputType: Int
    ) {
        enableEditTextInput(editText, inputType)
        clickOverlayView.isVisible = false
    }

    private fun makeOverlayEditTextClickable(
        editText: EditText,
        clickOverlayView: View,
        clickListener: () -> Unit
    ) {
        disableEditTextInput(editText)
        clickOverlayView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener()
        }
        clickOverlayView.isVisible = true
    }
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun disableEditTextInput(editText: EditText) {
        editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
        editText.isFocusable = false
        editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
        editText.isClickable = false
        editText.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun enableEditTextInput(editText: EditText, inputType: Int) {
        editText.inputType = inputType
        editText.isFocusable = true
        editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        editText.isClickable = true
        editText.setOnTouchListener(null)
    }
```

Usage:

```kotlin
// Make EditText editable
makeOverlayEditTextEditable(
    editText = binding.textInputLayout,
    clickOverlayView = binding.btnTextInputLayout,
    inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
)

// Make EditText clickable
makeOverlayEditTextClickable(
    editText = binding.textInputLayout,
    clickOverlayView = binding.btnTextInputLayout,
) {
    // Handle click
}
```

If this pattern is used all across the application, it makes sense to abstract this logic in the custom view.

Answer (score -1):

**Set this in your XML code, It works.**

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"