# How do I set multiple input types in an EditText on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, bitwise-operators, input-filtering

I am trying to create an `EditText` with auto-capitalization and auto-correction implemented. I have manually figured out how to add `InputFilter`s to allow auto-capitalization, though this only works *after* the first letter is typed, and I have had no luck with auto correction (I tried to create an InputFilter that used `AutoText`, but I'm not sure how all that works). Ideally, I could just use EditText.setInputType(...) to handle everything, but so far this has not worked. Is there a way to achieve this? My failed attempt is shown below (I just get normal input).

```
EditText mEditText = new EditText(this);
int inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
if (auto_capitalize) {
    inputType = mEditText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS;
}
if (auto_correct) {
    inputType = mEditText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT;
}
mEditText.setInputType(inputType);
```

**Please note, I am only interested in solutions for creating this `EditText` in code - not via XML.**

**Edit**

I found sound new documentation describing [TextKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TextKeyListener.Capitalize.html), however after trying to use this:

```
mEditText.setKeyListener(new TextKeyListener(TextKeyListener.Capitalize.CHARACTERS, true));
```

and using @farble1670's idea of using `setRawInputType`, so as not to affect the `KeyListener`s, there is still no change to the text.

Answer (score 42):

Through XML it would be setup like so.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

You simply add a pipe (`|`) between variables. I see you were doing it through code but I was just throwing this out there for reference.

Comment: my question specifically states that I am not interested in an `XML` solution.

Comment: I found your question while searching, I was putting the XML solution for the next person who finds this but was looking for an XML solution like I was....

Answer (score 14):

I hope you've found an answer to the question. The answer might help those those come to the thread later. So, you can set multiple tags in similar manner as you do in XML using a `|` (pipe). 
Something like:

```
EditText mEditText = new EditText(this);
mEditText.setInputType(InputTpe.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
```

Also, depending on your [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934842/1306419) you might want to use `setInputType`or `setRawInputype`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems like that should work. However, looking at the docs,

> The type of data being placed in a text field, used to help an input
> method decide how to let the user enter text. The constants here
> correspond to those defined by InputType. Generally you can select a
> single value, though some can be combined together as indicated.
> Setting this attribute to anything besides none also implies that the
> text is editable.
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

So it looks like in general, you can't expect to set two values.  The above link shows which flags can be combined together.

Also, if you look at android:setInputType, it says this maps to the `setRawInputType()` method, not `setInputType()`. You might try calling `setRawInputType()` in stead of `setInputType()`.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType(int)

Comment: Thanks, this got me headed into a new direction, and I found the `TextKeyListener`. Only thing is - that doesn't seem to work either...