# EditText.setInputType vs. setRawInputType

Tags: android, android-widget

What is the difference between EditText.setInputType and setRawInputType.

I have a field that should allow for all characters, but I have a mode button that switches between numeric and alpha keyboard.

So I want the numeric keyboard when they are "part number" search mode, but alpha keyboard when they are "description" search mode.

Android OS 2.2 or later.

Answer (score 11):

`setRawInputType()` is usually used when you initialize the view, in a constructor of a custom view or in `onCreate()` method of an activity, etc. It's the same as if you set inputType with the XML attribute `android:inputType`. For example:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
...
```

In your situation to change the mode of the soft keyboard that is shown for the editor
on the fly you have to call `setInputType()` which also takes care of restarting soft keyboard.

`setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)` changes keyboard layout to numeric text
`setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)` changes keyboard layout to normal text

Comment: Why setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) changes the EditText?

Comment: I had a bug where I was using raw, and this solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**setInputType**

Added in API level 3

public void setInputType (int type)

Set the type of the content with a constant as defined for EditorInfo#inputType. This will take care of changing the key listener, by calling setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener), to match the given content type. If the given content type is EditorInfo#TYPE_NULL then a soft keyboard will not be displayed for this text view. Note that the maximum number of displayed lines (see setMaxLines(int)) will be modified if you change the EditorInfo#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE flag of the input type.

**setRawInputType**

Added in API level 3
public void setRawInputType (int type)
Directly change the content type integer of the text view, without modifying any other state.

Related XML Attributes:

android:inputType

Answer (score 0):

setRawInputType() does not format the entered text, and this is one of the benefits of using it.