# How to set only integer numbers for EditText android (without comma)

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to set only Integer numbers for `EditText` ? (I would like to avoid to user to put comma)

Comment: I really feel like it was asked before but I cannot find an exact match. There is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645119/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittext-in-android) and [How to force EditText to accept only numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334314/how-to-force-edittext-to-accept-only-numbers)

Comment: I think you should reconsider your accepted answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try below attribute in your xml:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

Comment: Thanks, And programmatically ?

Comment: customEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); try this

Comment: Do **not** set `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` as this will allow for decimals. And you may want to use setInputType() instead of setRawInputType() [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933574/edittext-setinputtype-vs-setrawinputtype)

Answer (score 13):

You can set following in xml:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

Programmatically:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Thanks, And programmatically ?

Answer (score 3):

**Programmatically** you can achieve this like :

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use   `android:inputType="numberSigned"`  in `xml`: "`EditText` " 
Or

In  `Activity`:

```
                   EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_edit);
                   et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >>
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

above answers are correct. you can do it dynamically also from java -

```
EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code inside XML

**android:inputType="number"**

Below Other Options are:

In XML just add below line,

**android:digits="1234567890" ---> It will allow only numbers.**