# Prevent clicking on a button in an Activity while showing a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am having a problem with the interaction between an `Activity` and a `Fragment`.

I have a `main` `Activity` and an `into` `Activity` with layout buttons and text inputs. When I open the `Fragment` in the `main` `Activity`, I can still click on a button in the `Activity` and open the `Fragment` *again*, or enter text in the text inputs.

I've been searching for help two hours, and I haven't found the answer!

This is how I open the `Fragment` from the `Activity`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            SignUp fragment = new SignUp();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And this is picture:
[picture](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/u/42/4cgyxhI9/screen-shot-2015-03-02-a.png)

Comment: Just remove the listener from the button once it is clicked once and the fragment is added (if I understand what you are saying)

Comment: ok, but what to do with input fields? I can enter text into input field on activity layout from fragment.

Comment: Your question isn't really that clear with the information your provided. Your picture doesn't really show anything and your code just says you are adding a fragment to an activity. If you don't want your fields to be editable/focusable when the fragment is built just remove any event listeners.

Comment: This answer explains how to disable input  fields: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8942552/916451

Comment: Buttons can be disabled with the `setEnabled(boolean)` method.

Comment: It might be more effective to use two fragments, one with the controls that are currently in the activity, and the fragment you currently have. The button in the first fragment can tell the activity to show the second.

Comment: And yeah, your picture doesn't show the whole screen.

Comment: i thought that fragment auto freeze activity when it open. So i should disable buttons and inputs on activity when i open fragment, and when fragment is removed, i must to enable buttons and inputs, right?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and searched for hours to find a solution or the reason and I find it.

When you add a fragment to an activity, the functionally of the fragment and activity **both** will respond to the touch on the screen.

If you want to **not** touch through the fragment simply create an empty setOnTouchListener in the onViewCreated function of the fragment and it is done.

Code in Java

```
@Override
protected void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Code in Kotlin

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view!!.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent -> return@setOnTouchListener true }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to all. I found solution like a jjm say:

"It might be more effective to use two fragments, one with the controls that are currently in the activity, and the fragment you currently have. The button in the first fragment can tell the activity to show the second."

I just create new fragment with component of activity and replace fragments. 
But i still don't understand why we can click button on activity layout through fragment layout? Why is it usefull?