# How to use radio buttons in Java

Tags: java, android

I am making a project in android.

Basically I have added 2 radio buttons and 2 text fields.

I want to make one of the text fields grayed out depending on which of the radio buttons are selected.

I have no idea how to add this functionality.

Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to

- Hook the [radio buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) up to a click event.
- Find out the clicked button
- Set the [enabled property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4297763/261542) of [text field](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) to false to grey it out

The event handler pseudocode:

```
public void onradioButtonClicked ()
{
   if (ButtonClicked() == opt1)
   {
      txtTextField2.Enabled = false;
      txtTextField1.Enabled = true;
   }
   else
   {
      txtTextField2.Enabled = true;
      txtTextField1.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```