# enable and disable the edittext in android onclick of CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkedtextview

'

//this is first checkbox on click this it will enable f1 & n1

check1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);

//to disable the editext1

```
        f1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextf1);
         f1.setEnabled(false);
        f1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        f1.setFocusable(false);
         n1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextn1);
         n1.setEnabled(false);
        n1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        n1.setFocusable(false);
```

//this is second checkbox on click this it will enable f2 & n2

```
        check2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
```

//to disable the editext2 f2

```
        f2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextf2;
        f2.setEnabled(false);
        f2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        f2.setFocusable(false);
```

//to disable the editext2 n2

```
        n2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextn2);
        n2.setEnabled(false);
        n2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        n2.setFocusable(false);

        btnfinal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_final_submission);
```

//to enable the editext1 f1 & n1

```
        if (check1.isChecked()) {
            f1.setEnabled(true);
            f1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            f1.setFocusable(true);

            n1.setEnabled(true);
            n1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            nc1.setFocusable(true);


        }
```

//to enable the editext1 f2 & n2

```
        if (check2.isChecked()) {
            f2.setEnabled(true);
            f2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            f2.setFocusable(true);

            n2.setEnabled(true);
            n2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            n2.setFocusable(true);


        }**
```

'

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is in the code that you posted.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29433912/2784838

Comment: the problem is i can't able to enable and disable the edittext text box usig the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set listeners on your checkboxes, and then have to capture the events like when checkbox is checked and when check is removed to make your editexts work the way you want.Your current code will execute and it will take care of no future events because no listener is registered to capture the events.
The Simplest way to start is

```
CheckBox someCheckBox= (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.someID);
someCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                //CODE TO MAKE THE EDITTEXT ENABLED         
        }
        else 
           //CODE TO MAKE THE EDITTEXT DISABLED     

      }
    });
```

However there are other ways too,to perform this task, but you can kick off with this right away.

Comment: thanx @nobalG i have one more question can i apply the same way in radio button also??

Comment: Yea, You can...[See this simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323973/681929)

Comment: this code is working for only  one time when i  uckeck the box disable the it not working