# Disable EditText OnTouchListener or OnClickListener in custom view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I have a custom `View` which contains a `LinearLayout` in turn containing a `TextView` and and an `EditText`. When I will try to click on my custom view if I have pressed on the `TextView` the `LinearLayout` will receive the click but if I have pressed on the `EditText` it will not.

Below is a simplified version of my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_green_800" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So when I will press on the `EditText` I want the parent view (the `LinearLayout`) to receive the click.

I have tried below code:

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        binding = LayoutHeadingEdittextBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.headingtext,
                0, 0);
        if (attrs != null) {
            try {
                String hint = array.getString(R.styleable.headingtext_field_hint);
                String name = array.getString(R.styleable.headingtext_field_name);
                String text = array.getString(R.styleable.headingtext_field_text);
                Boolean isFocuable = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.headingtext_field_focus, true);
                if (!isFocuable) {
                    binding.edtTitle.setClickable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ((View) v.getParent()).performClick();
                        }
                    });
//                    binding.edtTitle.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    binding.edtTitle.setClickable(true);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusable(true);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                }
                binding.edtTitle.setHint(hint);
                binding.tvTitle.setText(name);
                binding.edtTitle.setText(text);
            } finally {
                array.recycle();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how i want to use it:

```
        <packagename.customView.HeadingEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_country"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_or_wechat"
            android:onClick="@{()->frag.onCountryClick(countryList)}"
            app:field_focus="false"
            app:field_hint="@string/country"
            app:field_name="@string/country"
            app:field_text='@{basicinfo.country_name!=null?basicinfo.country_name:""}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edt_address" />
```

But it is still not working So i think issue with databinding and click of my customview.

Comment: it may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297763/disabling-of-edittext-in-android/29433912

Comment: @AmjadKhan, no it's not. Disabling EditText is not the same thing with passing click actions to the parent view

Answer (score 2):

Programatically

```
//disable click action
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setEnabled(false);


//enable click action
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setEnabled(true);
```

xml:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: I will press Edittext I will not getting click of LinearLayout means if you click edittext linearlayout listener you need execute?

Comment: I have written my custom view's click on activity.. If i will press edittext portion then i will not getting click event of my activity.

Comment: Yup in few case ( from attrs if i will get as not focuable then I don't want edittext as editable ). but for other case i want it as editable.

Comment: Should i need to get parent of edittext and do peform click of it when it will click or touch ?

Comment: how you are decide when edittext is editable or non editable? using any array with true or false?

Comment: Or While opening exittext needs to non editable, after some action edittext is editable?

Comment: Check my question again you will get idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `EditText` :

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Programatically :

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

===============**EDIT**===============

```
 if (!isFocuable) {
                    binding.edtTitle.setClickable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnClickListener(null);
//                    binding.edtTitle.setEnabled(false);
                } else {

                    binding.edtTitle.setClickable(true);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusable(true);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnTouchListener(this);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

===============**EDIT**===============

Add in edittext

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

If this not works then try with this line also

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Actually this is my custom view so in few cases i want to edittext as edittext but in few case i want it as textview.. So if i will add this as static in xml then i will work same for all.

Comment: @HungryEnglish Check edited answer use this in if condition where you want to disable.

Comment: @HungryEnglish In your above code also add else and in else just add all that to true

Comment: Thank you for responding,  @Vishva Dave 
I have already set an attribute for it who can just pass me boolean for is editable or not.. so when this view is not editable i have set Click , focus ,Touch everything as null. But not working..

Comment: @HungryEnglish Yes that is what i am telling you have set all that when view is not editable but not when view is editable. so just add all that in else with true instead false

Comment: Boolean isFocuable = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.headingtext_field_focus, true);
                if (!isFocuable) {
                    binding.edtTitle.setClickable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusable(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    binding.edtTitle.setOnClickListener(null);
//                    binding.edtTitle.setEnabled(false);
                }
This is what i have tried..

Comment: what should i do this ?

Comment: Should i need to get parent of edittext and do peform click of it when custom view will click or touch ?

Comment: @HungryEnglish in this if add click listner to linear layout (parent layout)

Comment: I have edited question as what i have tried but still its not working.

Comment: Can you share me your email address so i can share my code for this particular class ?

Comment: My question is that how can i get my whole custom's click in activity ?

Comment: No its not working.. Do you want my whole custom class ?

Comment: @HungryEnglish Nope this is enough. I will find something and get back to you

Comment: Also remove that listner lines of onclick from java when you add this lines in xml. from edittext only

Comment: Is that any issue with databinding in this scenario ?

Comment: @HungryEnglish I don't think so. It is same as normal behavior.

Comment: I have add my custom view's activity xml.

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Comment: @HungryEnglish No I am not getting anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around.

```
// Inside HeadingEditText.kt
binding.edtTitle.setOnClickListener {
 this@HeadingEditText.performClick()
}
```

Set the `OnClickListener` at your Activity

```
edt_country.edtTitle.setOnClickListener {
  // foo action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS **NOT** A GOOD SOLUTION

JUST USABLE IN A CUSTOM-VIEW USING A `FrameLayout`

on your **parent** (ViewGroup) of contained `EditText`, override `onInterceptTouchEvent` method like this:

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

I use `EditText` inside a `FrameLayout` and **override** the method inside my `FrameLayout` and all of them used inside a recycler list item (xml)... and Worked fine click listener of recycler root item view...