# Disable editing/text input and paste from clipboard of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

We can disable editing text in `EditText` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8942552/7767664d

```
EditText.setFocusable(false)
```

But still we can paste some text to this view when you do long tap on it and paste button pops up

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/10182897 might this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise disable long click on edittext :

```
EditText.setLongClickable(false);
```

or directly in the xml:

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

**`JAVA`**

```
editTextOBJ.setLongClickable(false);
editTextOBJ.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

**`XML`**

```
 android:longClickable="false"
 android:textIsSelectable="false"
```