# Activate EditText when checking a CheckBox on Android Studio

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 3 CheckBoxes and next to each of them is an EditText for data-entry. How do I activate and deactivate the EditText next to each CheckBox depending on whether the CheckBox is marked or not? Sorry for my English.

[image]

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,##");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void calcularMedia(View v) {
        try {
            EditText notaP1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etP1);
            EditText notaP2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etP2);
            EditText notaP3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etP3);

            TextView tvNotaFinal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotaMedia);
            tvNotaFinal.setText("");

            if (notaValida(notaP1.getText().toString(), notaP2.getText().toString(), notaP3.getText().toString())) {
                String cad = "PUNTUAIÓN DEL ALUMNO: " + df.format(calculoNota(notaP1.getText().toString(), notaP2.getText().toString(),
                        notaP3.getText().toString()));
                TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotaMedia);
                texto.setText(cad);
            } else {
                Toast tError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Las notas no pueden ser superiores a 10", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tError.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 600);
                tError.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast tError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faltan campos por rellenar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            tError.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 600);
            tError.show();
        }
    }

    public int calculoNota(String notaP1, String notaP2, String notaP3) {
        int notaFinal = (Integer.parseInt(notaP1) + Integer.parseInt(notaP2) + Integer.parseInt(notaP3)) / 3;
        return notaFinal;
    }

    public boolean notaValida(String examen, String practicas, String actitud) {
        if (Double.parseDouble(examen) <= 10 && Double.parseDouble(practicas) <= 10 && Double.parseDouble(actitud) <= 10) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should look at the "How to ask a question" link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Code that you have tried and a sample product would help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for how to disable an EditText or how to tell whether a CheckBox is marked or not?

For the CheckBox marked or not check: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox

For the EditText disabling: [Disabling of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297763/disabling-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

use this code to achieve

```
  if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
        editText1.setEnabled(true);

// do the stuff you want to do when your checkbox is checked

    }else{
    editText1.setEnabled(false);

// do the stuff you want to do when your checkbox is not checked
```

}

**Repeat** the code for the other `checkBoxes` and other `editTexts` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose you set an [onCheckChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) for each of the Checkboxes and then activate/deactivate the EditTexts based on this. This seems like the most straightforward approach. You can do something like this:

**KOTLIN:**

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> edittext1.isEnabled = isChecked }
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> edittext2.isEnabled = isChecked }
checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> edittext3.isEnabled = isChecked }
```

**JAVA:**

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            editText1.setEnabled(isChecked);
        });
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            editText2.setEnabled(isChecked);
        });
checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            editText3.setEnabled(isChecked);
        });
```

This way, each of your EditTexts would always be enabled when their corresponding checkbox is checked.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax of your solution; I have added the main code. Could you implement your solution regarding my code?